# Access Polymer paper-toast outside the app class

Tags: javascript, web-component, polymer-2.x

I have a project, where I need to access a paper toast with the id `toastNewVersion` from outside the ES6 app class which extends the polymer Element

```
class WascApp extends Polymer.Element {
     _buttonOnTap() {
     this.$.toastNewVersion.open();
}
```

This code works just finde, as expected. But I want to open the toast from outside this class, in a basic `<script>` tag.

I tried using getElementById

```
document.getElementsByTagName('#toastNewVersion').open();
```

But this Object just equals null instead of the toast.

Any Ideas, how to open the toast?
Thanks!

Polymer2 BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way myself.

This opens a regular paper-toast from the index.html file, if the toast is inside the `app-element`s shadow-root:

`document.querySelector('app-element').shadowRoot.querySelector('#toastNewVersion').open();`